# Paged binary trees vs. AVL trees and/or B-trees

Tags: binary-tree, b-tree, avl-tree

How are paged binary trees different from AVL trees and/or B-trees?

Comment: So far I haven't had an explanation of what a paged binary tree is.

Comment: There’s a simple reason: I just overlooked that word completely. Apologies. Can’t really help you there but a quick search found this, which looks promising: http://www.isqa.unomaha.edu/haworth/isqa3300/fs010.htm

Answer (score 3):

In spite of the different structure of AVL and B-tree as stated by Konrad, usage of AVL and B-tree is also different, I think. B-tree generally used to implement indexing. Purpose of employing B-tree is to reduce disk I/O, while data of AVL-tree often resists totally in memory instead of partially in memory partially on disk like B-tree. Purpose of AVL-tree is to avoid the appearance of left/right branch tree in some extreme situation ensuring a perfect O(logn) time complexity when doing search operation.

Comment: Historically, you’re right. However, “recent” developments in hardware have shifted the balance massively in favour of B trees, due to cache locality issues. In fact, B trees that use cache lines optimally tend to outperform binary trees everywhere. For more information, have a look at the excellent study at http://idlebox.net/2007/stx-btree/, in particular the benchmarks: http://idlebox.net/2007/stx-btree/stx-btree-0.8.3/doxygen-html/speedtest.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the excellent Wikipedia articles on the topic.

Very briefly:

- AVL trees *are* binary search trees (i.e. binary trees used to impose an ordering on its elements). The difference is that AVL trees implement a self-balancing strategy to distribute the nodes evenly as to reduce the maximum depth of the tree.
- B trees are a generalization of binary search trees, i.e. they are no longer binary.